# Deleted almost the whole lubuntu

Tags: apt, lubuntu, live-usb, laptop

I tried installing VS Code and it removed all my pacakges, including dpkg and the desktop, Is there a way to fix it without losing the data? Maybe from the live cd?

Edit: Forgot to mention that the Try Lubuntu option doesn't work, only the install option.
Edit2: It also spams `ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: dma_direct_map_sg: overflow0x0000000010893000+512 of device mask ffffffff` when trying to "Try Lubuntu"

Answer (score 0):

You removed too many critical packages, so you must either restore the OS from a complete partition backup or reinstall the OS. It's a shame that you have to do this because of VSCode which isn't even a normal IDE like Visual Studio. As its name suggests, VSCode is more like an enhanced text editor.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to choose to (re)install your Ubuntu from Live media, choosing not to overwrite current partition. In any case, do a backup of (what's remaining) of your system first !!

Comment: Here is where the tricky part comes in, for some reason the Live Lubuntu option doesn't work. Only the intall option.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that I have an "Recover a broken system" option. I was able to copy all the data from the disk and full reinstall the system.